# What authentication libraries for PHP are not attached to a framework and meet these requirements?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Whenever I Google things like "php authentication library" I continue to come up with a ton of results of authentication libraries designed for Code Igniter.

What I am looking for is things like the following,

1. A robust library that handles login, logout, registration, login retrieval etc...
2. Very secure authentication possibly using sha-256+?
3. Library that can be integrated into any code, framework or not
4. Active project and community so that I can rely on it in the future.
5. Compatible with MySQL
6. Maybe some things I do not know about?

Comment: Instead of voting to close it without any comments, you could have asked me to reword it so that it was not asking for an opinion.

Comment: +1 I too am interested in a lightweight yet secure authentication system

Comment: Tried github?  If not then this sounds like a fun little project.  Or better yet, tried pulling what you want from a framework like Zend or symfony.  I know symfony has an authentication plugin that you could extract what you need.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am hoping my answer fits your needs , its in two parts :

1- Zend Acl + Zend + Auth :

1. very robust code and 100% unit tested
2. it could support any encryption method or create your own method
3. it can support any backend you like [`mysql` , `msssql` , or `even a session based auth`]
4. custom acl to fits your application needs
5. you may choose php5.2 version = ZF 1.11 or the php5.3  = ZF2 beta released the last week
6. in ZF2 beta  you could use the pyrus to package the required classes only , not the whole library http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Packaging-and-distribution-of-ZF2-td3597632.html
7. its very active project

2-symfony2 security component  :

1. in sf2 you combine the [`ACL` , `AUTH`] in very powerful library called security
2. symfony2 has the support of bundles , and the FOS UserBundle its the ideal match for my usage
3. you can use it in your own project as its

   Symfony's security component is available as a standalone PHP library for use inside any PHP project. http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html
4. it support many backend solutions , they called `providers`   you my see even create your own custom provider
5. you can even create many protected areas , in case you need it via `firewalls` , its basically as DMZs
6. support any encryption method you  might need , or create your own
7. its very active project too

Comment: Can you provide links to these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

probably you can try this link: [php user authentication libraries / frameworks ... what are the options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153117/php-user-authentication-libraries-frameworks-what-are-the-options)

zend_auth & codeigniter
it seems that the zend framework has good tools but it is overkill to do authentication only

ulogin, http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/

using social media login might also be another way

Comment: I think what he doesn't want is a CodeIgniter library. (P.S. I didn't donwvote)

Comment: yup i was reading the content did not pay attention to the title

Comment: Well, you can still edit your answer to reflect this new consciousness :) Because it its current form it is just wrong (for OP's needs)